# Square-and-equilateral-triangle aperiodic tiling with $\leq 4$ prototiles?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

There exist aperiodic tilings composed of square and equilateral-triangle tiles of unit side length: see https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/square-triangle/ and https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00247374/document . These tilings have five "prototiles" - that is, one really has five, not two, kinds of tiles (three triangles, two squares) and the entire tiling can be generated by repeatedly applying a substitution rule to one tile of any kind.

- Are there aperiodic tilings composed of square and equilateral-triangle tiles of unit side length with at most $4$ prototiles?
- Same question, but with squares and rhombi with angles $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$. (For rhombi with angles $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$, at least one such tiling is known: https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/ammann-beenker/ )
- Same two questions, but with $6$ prototiles, with all triangles appearing roughly equally often, and all squares appearing roughly equally often.

---

Anecdotical color: these are not idle questions, as there is a very prosaic real-life application. I would like to tile a bathroom floor that is roughly 9m^2. Squares, equilateral triangles and rhombi with angles $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$ are easily available as bathroom tiles. At the same time, anything that is not a square is expensive - and many companies have 3m^2 as the minimum order in a given color (though one can make a minimal order in a given color and different shapes).

Comment: If you consider mirror images to be different, the square-triangle tiling appears to have six prototiles and may be an answer to the third question.

Comment: Just since I did not mention: squares take exactly half of the space in the tiling in https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/square-triangle/  . (This is easy to show by computing eigenvectors.)